# Practical CMS, or WP solution for displaying comparisons between countries

Tags: wordpress, filtering, content-management-system

I have a set of about thirty countries with each of them scored on about fifty questions, plus maybe ten to twenty further paragraphs of un-comparable background (e.g., links to sources, particular info, ... ). Each can be displayed on its own, or a few (say, between two and five) have to be displayed next to other on all (or most) of the scored criteria, but without the background info; a bit like e.g. https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-comparison-chart/ to compare any Mac model ever, but then for only about thirty models/countries.

Further on I'd need to sort the scores (in the example, e.g. color code the Geekbench scores so green=highest and red=lowest), and do various stats (e.g. show the model's score relative to average score) but that doesn't seem to be the problem. It's part of a total website rewrite (now a one-page flat HTML 'brochure'-type site), so I'm quite free to choose how.

The solution I've cobbled together now is a WordPress custom post type for 'countries', with about fifty custom categories and fields of various types (numerical like the Geekbench score; text like a version number; radio/tickbox for features present/absent). Then sort-and-filter (e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_elements.asp or Metafizzy's Isotope). However this has been daunting, due to the sheer number of similarly-named variables etc; I can speed it up a bit with say Advanced Custom Fields (adding $500 cost over expected 10y lifespan) but all in all it feels wrong. Over time extra countries will get added, and several people will update existing scores/values.

I'm not doing anything I wouldn't be doing with a 30x50 Excel spreadsheet! Is there a more sensible approach, using either WordPress or another CMS? Am I overlooking a data-comparison plugin for WP (all I saw are for shopping solutions, often loading data straight from Amazon, or just making a 'choose-your-plan' display that doesn't update dynamically). I have the feeling I'm overlooking some obvious path.